# Given a palindromic string, in how many ways we can convert it to a non palindrome by removing one more more characters from it?

Tags: string, algorithm, math

Given a palindromic string, in how many ways we can convert it to a non palindrome by removing one more more characters from it?

For example if the string is "b99b". Then we can do it in 6 ways,

> i)   Remove 1st character : "99b"
>   ii)  Remove 1st, 2nd characters : "9b"
>   iii) Remove 1st, 3rd characters : "9b"
>   iv)  Remove 2nd, 4th characters : "b9"
>    v)   Remove 3rd, 4th characters : "b9"
>   vi) Remove 4th character : "b99"

How to approach this one?

PS:Two ways are considered different if there exists an i such that character at index i is removed in one way and not removed in another.

Comment: Also, if two different removals leave the same resulting string, do they count as two ways or as one way? @duDE No, you don't understand the question. In fact, it seems like you haven't put any effort in trying to understand it.

Comment: @dude - except for the case where removing a character still results in a palindrome.

Comment: Ok, so remove a character from a string using a recursive method ...

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Sorry, I don't have any clue for this one :(

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++ or any specific programming language.

Comment: This is probably a Dynamic Programming model based on intervals. Not sure. But clear enough, it doesn't belong to any specific programming language.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is conceptual and better be moved to programmers stackexchange


Answer (score 6):

There's an `O(n2)` dynamic programming algorithm for counting the number of palindromic subsequences of a string; you can use that to count the number of non-palindromic subsequences by subtracting the number of palindromic subsequences from the number of subsequences (which is simply 2<sup>n</sup>).

This algorithm counts subsequences by the criterion in the OP; two subsequences are considered different if there is a difference in the list of indices used to select the elements, even if the resulting subsequences have the same elements.

To count palindromic subsequences, we build up the count based on intervals of the sequence. Specifically, we define:

`Si,j` = the substring of `S` starting at index `i` and ending at index `j` (inclusive)

`Pi,j` = the number of palindromic subsequences of `Si,j`

Now, every one-element interval is a palindrome, so:

`Pi,i = 1` for all `i < n`

If a substring does not begin and end with the same element (i.e., `Si ≠ Sj`) then the palindromic subsequences consist of:

- Those which contain `Si` but do not contain `Sj`
- Those which contain `Sj` but do not contain `Si`
- Those which contain neither `Si` nor `Sj`

Now, note that `Pi,j-1` includes both the first and the third set of subsequences, while `Pi+1,j` includes both the second and the third set; `Pi+1,j-1` is precisely the third set. Consequently:

`Pi,j = Pi+1,j + Pi,j-1 − Pi+1,j-1` if `Si ≠ Sj`

But what if `Si = Sj`? In that case, we have to add the palindromes consisting of `Si` followed by a subsequence palindrome from `Si+1,j-1` followed by `Sj`, as well as the palindromic subsequence consisting of just the start and end characters. (Technically, an empty sequence is a palindrome, but we don't count those here.) The number of subsequences we add is P<sub>i+1,j-1</sub> + 1, which cancels out the subtracted double count in the above equation. So:

`Pi,j = Pi+1,j + Pi,j-1 + 1` if `Si = Sj`.

In order to save space, we can actually compute `Pi,i+k for 0 ≤ i < |S|-k` for increasing values of `k`; we only need to retain two of these vectors in order to generate the final result P<sub>0,|S|-1</sub>.

---

**EDIT**:

Here's a little python program; the first one computes the number of palindromic subsequences, as above, and the driver computes the number of non-palindromic subsequences (i.e. the number of ways to remove zero or more elements and produce a non-palindrome; if the original sequence is a palindrome, then it's the number of ways to remove one or more elements.)

```
# Count the palindromic subsequences of s
def pcount(s):
  length = len(s)
  p0 = [0] * (length + 1)
  p1 = [1] * length
  for l in range(1, length):
    for i in range(length - l):
      p0[i] = p1[i]
      if s[i] == s[i + l]:
        p1[i] += p1[i+1] + 1
      else:
        p1[i] += p1[i+1] - p0[i+1]
  # The "+ 1" is to account for the empty sequence, which is a palindrome.
  return p1[0] + 1

# Count the non-palindromic subsequences of s
def npcount(s):
  return 2**len(s) - pcount(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

this is not a complete answer, just a suggestion.

i would count the number of ways you can remove one or more characters and **keep** the string a palindrome. then subtract that from the total number of ways you can modify the string.

the most obvious way to modify a palindrome and keep it a palindrome is to remove the `i'th` and the `(n-i)'th` characters (n being the length of the string). there are `2^(n/2)` ways you can do that.

the problem with this approach is that it assumes only a symmetric modification can keep the string a palindrome, you need to find a way to handle cases such as `"aaaa"` where any sort of modification will still  result in a palindrome.

Comment: you  inverse problem to find total number of ways to  get palindrome within the String ??

Comment: any change in the string will either maintain it a palindrome or not, there's not third option, so finding one will give you the other.

Answer (score 1):

Brute force with memoization is pretty straightforward:

```
numWays(str): return 0 if str is empty
              return memo[str] if it exists
              memo[str] = numWays(str - firstChar) +
                          numWays(str - secondChar) +
                          ... +
                          1 if str is not a palindrome
              return memo[str]
```

Basically, you remove every character in turn and save the answer for the resulting string. The more identical characters you have in the string, the faster this is.

I'm not sure how to do it more efficiently, I will update this if I figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

For a string with N elements, there are 2^N possible substrings (including the whole string and the empty substring). Thus we can encode every substring by a number with a '1' bit at the bitposition for every omitted (or present) character, and a '0' bit otherwise. (assuming the length of the string is smaller then the number of bits in an int (size_t here), otherwise you would need an other representation for the bitstring):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char string[] = "AbbA";
int is_palindrome (char *str, size_t len, size_t mask);

int main(void)
{
size_t len,mask, count;

len = strlen(string);

count =0;
for (mask = 1; mask < (1ul <<len) -1; mask++) {
        if ( is_palindrome (string, len, mask)) continue;
        count++;
        }

fprintf(stderr, "Len:=%u, Count=%u \n"
        , (unsigned) len , (unsigned) count );

return 0;
}

int is_palindrome (char *str, size_t len, size_t mask)
{
size_t l,r,pop;

for (pop=l=0, r = len -1; l < r; ) {
        if ( mask & (1u <<l)) { l++; continue; }
        if ( mask & (1u <<r)) { r--; continue; }
        if ( str[l] == str[r] ) return 1;
        l++,r--; pop++;
        }
return (pop <1) ? 1: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Haskell version:

```
import Data.List

listNonPalindromes string = 
  filter (isNotPalindrome) (subsequences string)
    where isNotPalindrome str
            | fst substr == snd substr  = False
            | otherwise                 = True
           where substr = let a = splitAt (div (length str) 2) str
                          in (reverse (fst a), if even (length str) 
                                                  then snd a 
                                                  else drop 1 (snd a))

howManyNonPalindromes string = length $ listNonPalindromes string
```

*Main> listNonPalindromes "b99b"
["b9","b9","b99","9b","9b","99b"]
*Main> howManyNonPalindromes "b99b"
6